# Possible bug with angular-tinymce

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, angular-ui

Found what may possibly be a bug in the [angular-tinymce](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce) directive. I have a workaround, but it's ugly and looking for a better solution to this problem..

Basically, everything works fine except when you want more than 1 textarea on the page using the same configuration. For example:

```
@Html.TextArea("BodyContent", null, new { @class = "form-control", ng_model = "bodyContent", ui_tinymce = "tinyMCEOptions" })

@Html.TextArea("Translate_BodyContent", null, new { @class = "form-control", ng_model = "translation.bodyContent", ui_tinymce = "tinyMCEOptions" })
```

and the config as follows:

```
$scope.tinyMCEOptions = {
        selector: "textarea#BodyContent,textarea#Translate_BodyContent",
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor"
        ],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        image_advtab: true,
        templates: [
            { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
            { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
        ],
        content_css: tinyMCEContentCss
    };
```

They will both become TinyMCE editors as expected, but the problem is when sending the data to the server to save, then the second editor's value is ALWAYS blank... it seems that `ui-tinymce` is nto binding the second textarea. My  workaround was to make a copy of the above and set each textarea to have its own config:

```
    @Html.TextArea("BodyContent", null, new { @class = "form-control", ng_model = "bodyContent", ui_tinymce = "tinyMCEOptions" })

    @Html.TextArea("Translate_BodyContent", null, new { @class = "form-control", ng_model = "translation.bodyContent", ui_tinymce = "tinyMCEOptions2" })


$scope.tinyMCEOptions = {
        selector: "textarea#BodyContent",
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor"
        ],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        image_advtab: true,
        templates: [
            { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
            { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
        ],
        content_css: tinyMCEContentCss
    };

    $scope.tinyMCEOptions2 = {
        selector: "textarea#Translate_BodyContent",
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor"
        ],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        image_advtab: true,
        templates: [
            { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
            { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
        ],
        content_css: tinyMCEContentCss
    };
```

Rather hideous having to do that.. I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution than having repeated code.

**EDIT**

Part of the angular code here in case that helps:

```
var TranslationVM = function (item) {
    this.id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
    this.pageId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
    this.cultureCode = '';
    this.title = '';
    this.isEnabled = false;
    this.metaKeywords = '';
    this.metaDescription = '';
    this.bodyContent = '';

    if (item) {
        this.id = item.Id;
        this.pageId = item.PageId;
        this.cultureCode = item.CultureCode;
        this.title = item.Title;
        this.isEnabled = item.IsEnabled;
        this.metaKeywords = item.MetaKeywords;
        this.metaDescription = item.MetaDescription;
        this.bodyContent = item.BodyContent;
    }
};

pagesApp.controller('pageController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.emptyGuid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';

    $scope.id = $scope.emptyGuid;
    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.slug = '';
    $scope.metaKeywords = '';
    $scope.metaDescription = '';
    $scope.isEnabled = false;
    $scope.bodyContent = '';
    $scope.cssClass = '';
    $scope.cultureCode = '';
    $scope.translation = new TranslationVM();
    //etc
```

Comment: certainly cleaner ways of repeating an object without copy/paste twice. Noticed you have object property in one `ng-model` and a primitive in the other. Should always have a dot in ng-model. Also might be related to your issue

Comment: @charlietfl, It's not clear from my post, but those 2 textareas are unrelated; the properties are specified correctly. Please refer to my update above to see part of the angular controller

Comment: best suggestion is make a demo in plunker that replicates problem and post as an issue in the github repo for directive.

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for the suggestion; I just added the issue, here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/issues/95

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to duplicate the object because using JavaScript in 'use strict'; mode that will throw [this Error](https://www.google.com.ng/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Duplicate%20data%20property%20in%20object%20literal%20not%20allowed%20in%20strict%20mode). So the solution I found is to pass an empty object i.e {} into the second or subsequent tinymce directive attribute like this:

```
<textarea ui-tinymce="{}"> </textarea>
```